# What is the fixed point (in sense of a 2D function) of Radon transformation?

Tags: operator-theory, fixed-point-theorems, radon-transform

Looks that if I repetitively apply radon transform on image (use the output again as the input), I always get something like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sredT.png)

I'm curious what kind of function is that.

Comment: Given that the Radon transform can be related to the 2D Fourier transform, this seems like it should be related to eigenfunctions of the Fourier transform.

Comment: For the latter, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions_as_eigenfunctions_of_the_Fourier_transform.